# Defining and calling higher-order function composition functions with function pointers in C

Tags: c, function, function-pointers, function-composition

The Wikipedia article on [function types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_type) lists an interesting declaration of a "higher-order function composition function":

```
int (*compose(int (*f)(int), int (*g)(int)))(int);
```

As a learning exercise, I wanted to implement this in a test program, but failed, with the compiler throwing a number of warnings and errors. My attempt:

```
int a(int x) {
    return x + 1;
}

int b(int x) {
    return x * 2;
}

int (*compose(int (*f)(int y), int (*g)(int z)))(int x) {
    return (*f)(x) - (*g)(x);
}

int main(void) {
    int x = 5;
    int r = (*compose)((*a)(x), (*b)(x))(x);
    printf("Compose result for x = %d: %d\n", x, r);

    return 0;
}
```

I would be grateful for an explanation of how the declaration from Wikipedia differs from a simple function composition like `f(g(h(x)))` and how it may be implemented, preferrably with a simple program similar to mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `compose` function is declared to return a function pointer, but calculates and returns an `int` value instead.

Also `(*a)(x)` calls the `a` function and you pass the `int` result to `compose`, instead of a pointer to the function `a` itself. Same with `b`.

To solve your problem you first should call `compose` with pointers to the functions `a` and `b`:

```
int r = (*compose(&a, &b))(x);
```

Then you need to make `compose` return a pointer to a function, which includes creating the function to be returned:

```
int (*f1)(int);
int (*f2)(int);

int compose_helper(int x)
{
    return f1(x) - f2(x);
}

int (*compose(int (*f1_)(int), int (*f2_)(int)))(int)
{
    f1 = f1_;
    f2 = f2_;
    return &compose_helper;
}
```

In C there's really no nice way of doing this, as function composition can't be done at run-time and there needs to be global state.

---

As a side-note I really recommend that you create type-aliases for the function-pointers to make it all easier to read and understand.

As in

```
typedef int (fp_type)(int);

fp_type *f1;
fp_type *f2;

fp_type *compose(fp_type *f1_, fp_type *f2_) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where the errors are, but you haven't presented a working solution and I have so far not been able to create it. Please consider editing your answer so that my a and b functions are used in the composition.

Comment: @Theod'Or But `a` and `b` *are* used... They're stored in the global variables `f1` and `f2` which are called by `compose_helper`.

Comment: But of course! Answer accepted as it demonstrates how the Wiki declaration may be implemented.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues to address here.

- In C, you can't dynamically compose functions at run-time; only statically, at compile-time. Thus, you cannot achieve, with the signature you've chosen for `compose`, the run-time composition you're after. If `compose` is to return a (pointer to a) function - it can only return a pre-existing function. (*)
- In C, when you use the identifier of a function (which you've already defined) - the type is actually a function pointer already, i.e. the "invocation operator" (or the "parentheses operator") always applies to function pointers.
- Your syntax is a bit off.

Try this modification to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int a(int x) {
    return x + 1;
}

int b(int x) {
    return x * 2;
}

int compose(int (*f)(int y), int (*g)(int z), int x) {
    return f(x) - g(x);
}

int main(void) {
    int x = 5;
    int r = compose(a, b, x);
    printf("Compose result for x = %d: %d\n", x, r);

    return 0;
}
```

This [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/kdmpBX).

<sub>(*) - You could theoretically perform run-time compilation and return a link to the address of the resulting machine code, but that's not a language facility. In practice that's irrelevant</sub>

Comment: You have changed the function signature, simplifying the problem. I want to implement the Wiki declaration as given.

Comment: Although I can't accept this answer due to the changed signature, I like the solution for its simplicity - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In C you cannot create new functions at runtime; `compose` can only return a predefined function. Here is a short example for such a function:

```
int null(int x) { return 0; }
int f1(int x) { return x*x; }
int f2(int x) { return 2*x; }

int sub_f2_f1 ( int x ) { return f2(x)-f1(x); }
int sub_f1_f2 ( int x ) { return f1(x)-f2(x); }
/*...*/

int (*compose(int (*f)(int), int (*g)(int)))(int)
{
  if (f1==f2) return null;
  if (f2==null) return f1;
  if (f==f2 && g==f1) return sub_f2_f1;
  if (f==f1 && g==f2) return sub_f1_f2;
  /*...*/
  return 0;
}
```